# Is there a JSONEncoder equivalent for multipart requests in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, codable

I have a bunch of `Codable`s in my app that are *mostly* used for JSON, but sometimes I need to upload images along with them, so I use a multipart request. To do that, I've built up a lot of machinery to handle the boundaries, carriage returns, et cetera but it requires manually adding each key value pair to the list of parts. I feel like the Encodable/Decodable protocols were made to obsolesce exactly that kind of thing.

With a JSONEncoder all I have to do is say `encoder.encode(myCodable)` and it spits out a `Data` representation of the JSON for that `Codable`, respecting the various coding keys and values.

**Is there some sort of `MultipartEncoder` that I could use in a similar way? If not, could you point me to some resources for creating a custom `Encoder`?**

Here's an example of what I currently do. Say we have a `Codable` called `Post`:

```swift
class Post: Codable {
  var userId: Int?
  var title: String?
  var text: String?
  var headerImage: Data?
}
```

I have built some classes called `MultipartComponent` (which holds a given key/value pair) and `MultipartFormData` (which holds an array of `MultipartComponent`s that I use to create an `InputStream` out of those components to assign to `URLRequest.httpBodyStream`). So to turn `Post` into an `InputStream` I have to make a `MultipartComponent` from each of it's properties, put those into an array, put that array into a `MultipartFormData`, and then get an `InputStream` from that:

```swift
extension Post {
  func multipartData() -> MultipartFormData {
    var parts = [MultipartComponent]()
    if let userId = userId {
      parts.append(MultipartComponent(data: "\(userId)".data(using: .utf8) ?? Data(), name: "post[user_id]", fileName: nil, contentType:"text"))
    }
    if let title = title {
      parts.append(MultipartComponent(data: title.data(using: .utf8) ?? Data(), name: "post[title]", fileName: nil, contentType:"text"))
    }
    if let text = text {
      parts.append(MultipartComponent(data: text.data(using: .utf8) ?? Data(), name: "post[text]", fileName: nil, contentType:"text"))
    }
    if let headerImage = headerImage {
      parts.append(MultipartComponent(data: headerImage, name: "post[header_image]", fileName: "headerImage.jpg", contentType:"text"))
    }
    return MultipartFormData(parts: parts, boundary: "--boundary-\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)-boundary--")
}
```

Once I've written this extension, I can create a `URLRequest` for it like so:

```swift
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
urlRequest.httpBodyStream = post.multipartData().makeInputStream()
...
```

This works... fine. Problem is, as you can imagine, writing that extension gets tedious if there are more than a handful of properties, not to mention the pain of adding or removing properties. What I *want* is to create a custom encoder (or use an existing one) that will allow me to take any existing Codable and encode it as a multipart form instead of JSON. Is there something that I could use to do something like `multipartEncoder.encode(post)` to get the data representation or input stream for the Codable?

Comment: what is the multipartencoder ? can you share your multipartencoder code sample in your project to focusing on the question ?

Comment: @zeytin example added

Comment: I think you may find that this is more complicated than you'd like. See, for example, [this XMLCoder implementation](https://github.com/MaxDesiatov/XMLCoder). I'm not sure if the overhead in trying to use `Codable` for this pattern is worth the effort (as appealing as it might seem at first blush). Far simpler might be to write a "dictionary" output for your type and then write a rendition of your multipart encoder that can consume that. Or reflection...

Comment: @Rob thank you! That's pretty close to what I'm looking for as an example. I'd like to open source it once I've written it, so I'm ok if it's a lot of work :)

Comment: Unrelated, and very minor, observation: I might suggest avoiding that `nil`-coalescing operator approach. E.g., rather than `if let text = text { parts.append(MultipartComponent(data: text.data(using: .utf8) ?? Data(), name: "post[text]", fileName: nil, contentType:"text")) }`, perhaps `if let data = text?.data(using: .utf8) { parts.append(MultipartComponent(data: data, name: "post[text]", fileName: nil, contentType:"text")) }`